# Rails - how to sort by associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have a Product model which has_many Reviews.

In my controller, I'd just like to order the array of Products by the count of how many reviews there are.

## Controller

```
@search = Product.search_attributes(params[:search])
@products = @search.sort_by_reviews_count
```

## Product model:

```
def self.sort_by_reviews_count
  self.sort! { |x,y| x.reviews.count <=> y.reviews.count }
end
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `sort!' for #<Class:0x007ff019ebf468>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Does it work if you convert it to an array first? `all.sort!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to sort your `Product < ActiveRecord::Base` class. That doesn't make sense.

You might be able to sort your associations at the database using an AR relation, but I'm not sure how.

If you don't mind doing the sorting in the application, you should be able to do this:

```
def self.sort_by_reviews_count
  self.all.sort! { |x,y| x.reviews.count <=> y.reviews.count }
end
```